# How use Mobx 6 storage with React 17?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I'm completely confused with the rules of mobX - react . Some methods in another project work, but not in this test.

Below is the code of my components from the test application

App.js

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
import ComponentFirst from './components/ComponentFirst/ComponentFirst';
import ComponentSecond from './components/ComponentSecond/ComponentSecond';


const App: FC = observer(() => {
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <ComponentFirst />
        <ComponentSecond />
      </div>
  );
})

export default App;
```

ComponentFirst

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import {testStoreFirst} from '../../stores/testStoreFirst';

const ComponentFirst : FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>It is First Component</h3>
            <p>{testStoreFirst.testText}</p>
            <p>{testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore}</p>
            <button onClick={() => {testStoreFirst.setTestText('New text after click')}}>Click me!!!</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentFirst;
```

ComponentSecond

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import {testStoreSecond} from '../../stores/testStoreSecond';
import {testStoreFirst} from '../../stores/testStoreFirst';

const ComponentSecond : FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>It is Second Component</h3>
            <p>{testStoreSecond.textFromFirstStore}</p>
            <button onClick={() =>{testStoreFirst.setTextForSecondTestStore('I can change text from second storage')}}>Click me!!!</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ComponentSecond;
```

testStoreFirst

```
import { makeAutoObservable} from "mobx";

class TestStoreFirst  {
    testText='It is test text from mobX storage';
    textForSecondTestStore='this text from First Store!!!';

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }


    setTextForSecondTestStore = (newText : string) => {
        this.textForSecondTestStore = newText;
    }

    setTestText = (newText: string) => {
        this.testText = newText;
        console.log('It is not work');
    }

}

export const testStoreFirst = new TestStoreFirst()
```

testStoreSecond

```
import {makeAutoObservable} from 'mobx'
import {testStoreFirst} from './testStoreFirst'

class TestStoreSecond {
    textFromFirstStore = testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }
}

export const testStoreSecond = new TestStoreSecond();
```

My question

My App component is subscribed via observe to changes in stores. By clicking on the first button, in 1 component the text in the storage and, accordingly, the text should change, but it does not change. And In the second component, the value for the text field is taken from testStoreSecond. There, the text field is taken from testStoreFirst . When the button is clicked, the method from testStoreFirst is executed which should change the text, but it does not change.

I've read the documentation, but I still don't fully understand how to use the store and achieve "reactivity" and instant change of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap every component that uses any observable values with `observer` decorator, like you did with an `App`. But in case of `App` it's actually useless because you are not using observable values there. So just wrap other components and it should work fine.

As for this line `textFromFirstStore = testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore` it won't work like you expected because you just assigned value of `testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore` to `textFromFirstStore` and that's it.

To make such value reactive you need to use `computed` value. To make `computed` you just need to setup a getter function, like that:

```
class TestStoreSecond {
  // ...

  get textFromFirstStore() {
    return testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore
  }

  // ...
}

// And in React access it just as before (it's a getter, not a function)
<p>{testStoreSecond.textFromFirstStore}</p>
```

Comment: An Observer around any component that uses data from the store. OK! Thanks, got it)

As for reactivity. Do I need to add this get function instead of assigning direct data from the storage?

That is, instead of {testStoreFirst.textForSecondTestStore} , you need to use {textFromFirstStore()} , which get ?
  I hope that I correctly understood this logic? We're not accessing the values in the store directly, but are accessing them via get textFromFirstStore() , which is the so-called @computed in mobx ?

Comment: Getter function is for `TestStoreSecond` to make `textFromFirstStore` reactive (`textFromFirstStore ` will be updated every time `textForSecondTestStore` is updated). And because it's a getter you just use it as regular variable. I've updated the answer to make it a bit more clear. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It is perfect! Thank you very much for help!  Today I will try it. I just don't know the get and set functions yet. I will study them!)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted for future reference if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure. I just haven't had time to test it yet.

Comment: Yes, it is work. Thank you again!)

Comment: I have marked this issue as resolved. I hope I did it right. This is my first question on this site.